# Emacs freezes after Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el

Tags: emacs

I've got trouble with my emacs. It freezes after launch (even with `--debug-init`) I cannot perform any action with that emacs window, and I have to kill its process rather than close (`C-x C-c` or any other keystroke doesn't work).
With this message in scratch buffer:
`Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...done`
 However it does launch with `-q` option.

I found that after removing `elpa/` directory package installer has problems with installing helm-company (it simply freezes there instead), and that's what I know so far.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Your question is unclear. It risks being closed unless you add more and better information. In particular, what do you mean by "freezes"? What exactly are the symptoms? Does this happen even if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If so, and if you can give a reproducible recipe then consider reporting it as a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. If not, recursively bisect your init file to find out what you are doing that is causing the problem (whatever it is).

Comment: I have a similar problem. It does start fine with -Q. 
Strangely enough, this is a multi-user system, both using the exact same .emacs.d directory. I have seen it fail often when logged in as the second user (but not consistently) never as the first.
I am not sure what to do to diagnose further. This is on Ubuntu 16.04 xenial with Emacs 24.5.1

Comment: A restart of the system solves this - sometimes...
I had posted the comment after trying this several times,
so any pointers on how to debug this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, problem was solved when I switched to Emacs 24.4.1 because of some of packages if I remember it was helm, but I might be wrong.